# When should the Battlestar Galactica episode "The Plan" be watched with respect to the episode "No Exit"?

Tags: suggested-order, battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

I see that the special "The Plan" is generally recommended to be viewed *after* the episode "No Exit", although I hear it could very well be viewed *before* that episode, but the reasoning there is undocumented.

I am looking for the ultimate viewing order, meaning I want to inspect it myself. Anybody know the arguments for both so I can choose?